# Errors after updating packages in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

[image: The Error After Updating Packages]

I have Updated Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Android.Support to latest Version. Many of the written code is shown in red. I cannot build any code.
None of the Android Classes are working and an error message is shown:

```
the name "<classname>" doesnt exist in current context.
```

Another error message while compliling is:

```
This Project references NuGet Packages that are missing.
```

What can be done?

Comment: You could try some stuff:
- Clean your project, and build again
- Remove all nuget packages and add them again

Comment: @Martijn I have done that too... but sadly that didnt help.

Comment: Have you re-added all packages that you use? What nuget package does it say you miss?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.1.3.5.6335 is missing.

Comment: Did you previously manually add a reference to Forms? Maybe you could remove the Forms Nuget package, then remove any references to it, and add it again.

Comment: First I updated Forms and I got the error. So I removed the forms and added them again but still the error was not resolved.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your packages and references in the project?

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can try:

1. Remove the Xamarin.Forms nuget package and add it back
2. Manually add a reference to the Xamarin.Forms.dll after installing the nuget package